# MySQL internal session check?

Tags: php, mysql

This problem sounds so easy but I cannot find the error:
My PHP scripts post a text to a MySQL db. This is backed by an user-management-system. So only the user who posted the text is able to see it. Now I want to integrate a "share-function". User a enables user b to see one of user's a postings in his text overview (little bit like a note share function).

After sharing a note with user b, he can see the note in his overview but when opening the note to see the details it's not working.

On the technical side I have 3 tables:
1.) notes - with the fields title, text and user 
2.) user - id, name and password
3.) invites - NoteID, fromID and toID

My SQL statement for the invite overview is (which is working):

```
SELECT * FROM notes a, invites b WHERE (b.toID = '$UserID') AND (b.ItemID = a.id) AND a.Deleted = 0
```

But when I have this statement

```
SELECT * FROM notes a, invites b WHERE (a.id = '$ItemID') AND ((a.User = '$username') OR (b.toID = '$userid'))
```

in the detail view it's not working. Even if I have this very simple (and unsecure) SQL it's not working:

```
SELECT * FROM notes WHERE ID = '$ItemID'
```

I'm really desperate and my only explanation (which is very unrealistic) is that MySQL has a kind of internal security check which does not allow displaying content from strangers :S

any ideas? Thanks a lot

Comment: What is the difference between ItemID and NoteID?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that this is your only problem, but you are doing a cross join by accident. MySQL will probably try to create a huge number of rows in the result set and then time out. Use the `JOIN ... ON ...` syntax to help you remember to specify how you want to perform the join:

```
SELECT *
FROM notes a
JOIN invites b
ON ... -- put some join condition here
WHERE (a.id = '$ItemID') AND ((a.User = '$username') OR (b.toID = '$userid'))
```

I'm guessing that you want something like this:

```
ON b.NoteID = a.ID
```